# Creating tensorflow session in MATLAB via python

Tags: python, matlab, tensorflow

I'm trying to use Tensorflow through MATLAB, I first created a script "mymod" like this:

```
# mymod.py
import tensorflow as tf
def run():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        a = 1
    return a
```

Run the script function "run()" in MATLAB command window:

```
py.mymod.run()
```

Then I got this error:

```
Error using errors_impl>__exit__ (line 473)
Python Error: NotFoundError: No session factory registered for the given     
session options: {target: "" config:} Registered factories are {}.

Error in session>__init__ (line 622)
      self._session = tf_session.TF_NewDeprecatedSession(opts, status)

Error in session>__init__ (line 1482)
    super(Session, self).__init__(target, graph, config=config)

Error in mymod>run (line 4)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Can you successfully run a simple test Python script from MATLAB, that doesn't use tensorflow?

Comment: yes, simple Python script works